# Converting a DataTable to my List<T>

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

```
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(rdr);
            return dt;
```

`DataTable tb = new DataTable();` to the `List<Details> objList = new List<Details>`.

```
            foreach (var obj in dt)
            {
                var item = new Details();
                item.ID = obj.ID;
                item.Dosage = obj.Dosage;
                item.Drug = obj.Drug;
                item.Patient = obj.Patient;
                item.Date = obj.Date;

                results.Add(item);
            }
```

the idea is here but there is an error in **dt** in forceach(var obj in dt)

Comment: Convert how exactly?

Comment: passing all the value from datable to list of object

Comment: So what did you try? What are the fields of `Detail`? What are the fields of your data table?

Comment: Details have its own class with properties Id, Dosage, Drug, Patient and Date and The datatable get all its value from my select query select * from details;

Comment: The conversion depends deeply in the database table data types, you are missing info on your table scructure. BTW, the xamarin tag looks not related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to

1. Execute reader
2. Read the coursor
3. Create your class instances
4. Collect these instances into a `List<T>`

Something like this

```
   // List which will be used to collect records from the query
   List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

   ...
   cmd.CommandText = sql;

   //DONE: execute reader; wrap IDisposable into using
   using (SqliteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
     //DONE: read each cursor's record
     while (rdr.Read()) {
       //DONE: Turn each record into MyClass instance
       MyClass item = new MyClass();

       //TODO: Assign properties
       item.Property1 = Convert.ToString(rdr[0]);
       item.Property2 = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[1]); 
       ...  

       //DONE: Finally, collect all the intances created into the list 
       list.Add(item);
     }      
   } 
   ...
```

Comment: you are the men, how did you type this stuff? :)